# Elegant Haskell case/error handling

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to better understand how to handle error cases in haskell and made wrote some code to help me with that.

**Is there a better way (more elegant, shorter, more generic) of handling multiple alternatives (like nested case expressions)? Any nice tutorials about the topic?**

A made-up type for this example.
This is a bit simplified because mostly there are not only these nested
types but dependent values which can only be retrieved sequentially (e.g.
reading an id from stdin, then retrieving the record for this id from a
database). *So the nesting here should demonstrate a case where the inner value will only be available when the outer value is already checked for `Nothing`. Please see my [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13252889/elegant-haskell-case-error-handling-in-sequential-monads) for a better example.*

```
type MyType = (Maybe (Maybe Int))
```

### The goal

Return the int when it is less than 10, on other cases (greater or
equal 10, Nothing or Just Nothing) return diferent error messages.

```
process Nothing ~> "error"
process (Just Nothing) ~> "error2"
process (Just (Just 20)) ~> "error3"
process (Just (Just 5)) ~> "5"
```

### Tried so far:

#### Naiive implementation.

Suffers from "creeping indentation"

```
process :: MyType -> String
process t = case t of
        Nothing -> "error"
        Just a -> case a of
                    Nothing -> "error2"
                    Just b -> if b < 10 then show b else "error3"
```

#### maybe function

Using the maybe function, which makes it shorter but also harder to read.

```
process2 :: MyType -> String
process2 t = maybe "error" (\a -> maybe "error2" (\b -> if b < 10 then show b else "error3") a) t
```

#### Pattern matching

Nicest solution so far but is not possible in more complex
cases (see comment above type definition of MyType).

```
process3 :: MyType -> String
process3 Nothing = "error"
process3 (Just Nothing) = "error2"
process3 (Just (Just a))
  | a < 10 = show a
  | otherwise = "error3"
```

A gist with the code can be found under https://gist.github.com/4024395

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nested `Maybes` is indeed messy.

### Suggestion 1: roll a custom error type and use `Either`

```
data MyError = ReadError | TooBig Int

explain :: MyError -> String
explain ReadError = "Error: the requested Int could not be found"
explain TooBig i = "Error: the supplied Int should be at most 10, but it was " ++ show i
```

Now use Either to mix Ok values (Right) and error values (Left):

```
type MyType = Either MyError Int
```

Now lots of handy functions like `either` and the Applicative and Monad instances for `Either a` make it easy to write nice code:

```
myAdd :: MyType -> MyType -> MyType
myAdd i1 i2 = (+) <$> i1 <*> i2
```

is nicely applicative, or

```
myMult i1 i2 = do
    a <- i1
    b <- i2
    return $ a * b
```

if you prefer monadic notation.
We can use `either` in a crash-the-program way

```
myShow :: MyType -> String
myShow = either (error.explain) show
```

or a tell-me-anyway way:

```
process4 :: MyType -> String
process4 = either explain show
```

### Suggestion 2: roll a custom type

```
data MyType' = OK Int | ReadError | TooBig Int
```

and use pattern matching. This isn't as nice as suggestion 1 in my veiw, because you lose the higher order function reuse, but it's better than `Maybe (Maybe Int)`

### Suggestion 3: Use the Error monad

Read up about [Control.Monad.Error](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/mtl/1.1.0.2/doc/html/Control-Monad-Error.html) and use the supplied functions or the `ErrorT` monad transformer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, especially the monadic notation looks quite nice. I'm not yet sure how to apply this to my initial problem. I think I understand that I could change my `process` function to `:: MyType -> MyError` and call `explain $ process x` to get the desired result, but how to implement `process` in this case?

Comment: My `process4` function works like your `process` functions. It shows the result if it's OK, and the error message if not.

Comment: I added some explaination why I used a nested `Maybe` in my example.

Comment: @SvenKoschnicke That makes sense, yes. I still think it's better to roll your own error type, though. `Maybe (Maybe Int)` does guarantee that you can't get a too-big error if you got a couldn't-read error, but the `data` declaration also gives you that guarantee. There's nothing stopping you from concluding `ReadError` early on and `TooBig 12` later - you don't have to wrap at every stage.

Comment: I have chosen a bad example, so I have created a new question with a (hopefully) better example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13252889/elegant-haskell-case-error-handling-in-sequential-monads For this question, your answer is correct, thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I think the most readable way is the `maybe` function you already tried, just a little bit prettified by avoiding lambdas (pointfree style) and using `maybe` even for the innermost check (by replacing `if` with `mfilter`):

```
import Control.Monad(mfilter)

process2 :: MyType -> String
process2 =  
  maybe "error"  $ 
  maybe "error2" $ 
  maybe "error3" 
  show . mfilter (<10) . Just
```