# Elegant haskell case/error handling in sequential monads

Tags: haskell

Because I oversimplified in my [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13251388/elegant-haskell-case-error-handling) before, I would like to give a more clear example here.

How can I handle situations where I have to check for certian conditions in a sequential way without nesting multiple cases? With "sequential way" I mean getting a value (e.g. from stdin), checking this value for a certain condition and depending on the outcome getting another value and so on.

Example:

```
sequen :: IO String
sequen = do
  a <- getLine
  case a of
    "hi" -> do
      putStrLn "hello!"
      b <- getLine
      case b of
        "how are you?" -> do
          putStrLn "fine, thanks"
          return "nice conversation"
        _ -> return "error 2"
    _ -> return "error 1"
```

I know that there are better ways to write such a chat bot, it should just demonstrate the sequential nature of the problem. As you can see, with every nested case, the code also gets indented deeper.

Is there a way to better structure such code? I'm thinking of handling the "errors" on one place and describing the "success-path" without the error handling distributed all over it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Of course.  This is precisely what `EitherT` was made for.  You can get it from `Control.Monad.Trans.Either` in the `eitherT` package.

```
import Control.Monad.Trans.Class
import Control.Monad.Trans.Either

main = do
    e <- runEitherT $ do
        a <- lift getLine
        case a of
            "hi" -> lift $ putStrLn "hello!"
            _    -> left 1
        b <- lift getLine
        case b of
            "how are you?" -> lift $ putStrLn "fine, thanks!"
            _              -> left 2
        return "nice conversation"
    case e of
        Left  n   -> putStrLn $ "Error - Code: " ++ show n
        Right str -> putStrLn $ "Success - String: " ++ str
```

`EitherT` aborts the current code block whenever it encounters a `left` statement, and people typically use this to indicate error conditions.

The inner block's type is `EitherT Int IO String`.  When you `runEitherT` it, you get `IO (Either Int String)`.  The `Left` type corresponds to the case where it failed with a `left` and the `Right` value means it successfully reached the end of the block.

Comment: Awesome. Exactly what I wanted to know. Thank you!

Comment: On the note of EitherT, I wrote a blog post on this which was quite well received: http://ocharles.org.uk/blog/posts/2012-07-24-in-praise-of-EitherT.html

Comment: @ocharles I read that a while ago and thought that it should be the solution to my problem but I couldn't apply it until now. You could link to this question in your post :)

Comment: @Gabriel do you intend for EitherT to completely replace the ErrorT use cases?  I've been using ErrorT for a long time, but sometimes find it annoying to declare the Error instance for all of my exception classes.

Comment: I would really like `EitherT` to replace `ErrorT` for all possible use cases.  The issue is that Edward Kmett and I are having a hard time convincing Ross Patterson to either (a) remove the `Error` constraint from `ErrorT` or (b) add `EitherT` to `transformers`.  That's the hold-up at the moment.

Answer (score 5):

I wrote a series of posts a while back going over my own learnings of the `Either` & `EitherT` types. You can read it here: http://watchchrislearn.com/blog/2013/12/01/working-entirely-in-eithert/

I use the `errors` package to get a bunch of nice helpers around using EitherT (`left` and `right` functions for instance to return lifted versions of `Left` and `Right`).

By extracting your potential failure conditions into their own helpers, you can make the mainline of your code read totally sequentially, with no case statements checking results.

From that post, you can see how the `runEitherT` section is a sequential chunk of work, it just happens to have the failure mechanics of `EitherT`.  Obviously this code is fairly contrived to show how `MaybeT` plays inside of `EitherT` as well. In real code it'd just be the story you were wanting to tell, with a single `Left`/`Right` at the end.

```
import Control.Error
import Control.Monad.Trans

-- A type for my example functions to pass or fail on.
data Flag = Pass | Error

main :: IO ()
main = do
  putStrLn "Starting to do work:"

  result <- runEitherT $ do
      lift $ putStrLn "Give me the first input please:"
      initialText <- lift getLine
      x <- eitherFailure Error initialText

      lift $ putStrLn "Give me the second input please:"
      secondText <- lift getLine
      y <- eitherFailure Pass (secondText ++ x)

      noteT ("Failed the Maybe: " ++ y) $ maybeFailure Pass y

  case result of
    Left  val -> putStrLn $ "Work Result: Failed\n " ++ val
    Right val -> putStrLn $ "Work Result: Passed\n " ++ val

  putStrLn "Ok, finished. Have a nice day"

eitherFailure :: Monad m => Flag -> String -> EitherT String m String
eitherFailure Pass  val = right $ "-> Passed " ++ val
eitherFailure Error val = left  $ "-> Failed " ++ val

maybeFailure :: Monad m => Flag -> String -> MaybeT m String
maybeFailure Pass  val = just $ "-> Passed maybe " ++ val
maybeFailure Error _   = nothing
```

Comment: Nice example! Thanks for pointing out that you can put the cases in separate functions. Makes the main function much nicer to read.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are necessarily in the `IO` monad, you are better off using the `IO` monad's error handling capabilities instead of stacking an error monad on top of `IO`.  It avoids all of the heavy `lift`ing:

```
import Control.Monad ( unless )
import Control.Exception ( catch )
import Prelude hiding ( catch )
import System.IO.Error ( ioeGetErrorString )

main' = do
  a <- getLine
  unless (a == "hi") $ fail "error 1"
  putStrLn "hello!"
  b <- getLine
  unless (b == "how are you?") $ fail "error 2"
  putStrLn "fine, thanks"
  return "nice conversation"

main = catch main' $ return . ioeGetErrorString
```

In this case, your errors are simply `String`s, which are thrown by `IO`'s `fail`, as a `userError`.  If you want to throw some other type, you will need to use `throwIO` instead of `fail`.

Answer (score 1):

At some point [the `EitherT` package was deprecated](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/EitherT) (though [`transformers-either`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-either) offers a similar API). Fortunately there's an alternative to `EitherT` that doesn't even require installing a separate package.

The standard Haskell installation comes with the [`Control.Monad.Trans.Except`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Except.html) module (from the `transformers` package, which is bundled with GHC), which behaves almost identically to `EitherT`. The resulting code is *almost* identical to the code in [Gabriella Gonzalez's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13253245), but using [`runExceptT`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Except.html#v:runExceptT) instead of `runEitherT` and [`throwE`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Except.html#v:throwE) instead of `left`.

```hs
import Control.Monad.Trans.Class
import Control.Monad.Trans.Except

main = do
    e <- runExceptT $ do
        a <- lift getLine
        case a of
            "hi" -> lift $ putStrLn "hello!"
            _    -> throwE 1
        b <- lift getLine
        case b of
            "how are you?" -> lift $ putStrLn "fine, thanks!"
            _              -> throwE 2
        return "nice conversation"
    case e of
        Left  n   -> putStrLn $ "Error - Code: " ++ show n
        Right str -> putStrLn $ "Success - String: " ++ str
```

(Note that the aforementioned [`transformers-either`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-either) package is in fact a wrapper for `ExceptT` designed for providing compatibility with code that still uses `EitherT`.)

Answer (score 0):

Warning: fellow Haskell newbie answering.

You can avoid this sort of staircasing with the Maybe monad. Good example at the start of [this chapter](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/monads.html)

However, you'd want something similar with a monadic Either (presumably there is one) since you're returning error codes.

The basic idea being that once you've got a "Left 1" error you'll short-circuit any future steps (because of lazy evaluation).

Comment: Ah, I see I was on the right track according to @Gabriel below.

Comment: Because of lazy evaluation?  Or because of the definition of the monad instance for `Either`?