# Haskell - Left arrow vs nested case statements

Tags: haskell, monads

I've unsuccessfully looked everywhere for a definition/description of this. While I was *Haskell Programming from First Principles*, in the monads intro chapter (pg. 763), it showed this example of a nested case statement:

```hs
mkSphericalCow :: String -> Int -> Int -> Maybe Cow
mkSphericalCow name' age' weight' =
    case noEmpty name' of
        Nothing -> Nothing
        Just nammy ->
            case noNegative age' of
                Nothing -> Nothing
                Just agey ->
                    case noNegative weight' of
                        Nothing -> Nothing
                        Just weighty ->
                            weightCheck
                                (Cow nammy agey weighty)
```

It said that it could be replaced by:

```hs
mkSphericalCow' :: String -> Int -> Int -> Maybe Cow
mkSphericalCow' name' age' weight' = do
    nammy <- noEmpty name'
    agey <- noNegative age'
    weighty <- noNegative weight'
    weightCheck (Cow nammy agey weighty)
```

How in the world does this work!? What is this called? The closest I could find is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13252076/11059315), which describes it as "monadic notation".

Comment: It indeed uses the monad instance of `Maybe`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `do` expression is desugared to a chain of `>>=` functions. The [Haskell report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/exps.html#sect3.14) describes how to desugar `do` expressions. In your case, it means the expression is desugared to:

```
mkSphericalCow' :: String -> Int -> Int -> Maybe Cow
mkSphericalCow' name' age' weight' = noEmpty name' >>= (\nammy -> noNegative age' >>= (\agey -> nonNegative weight' >>= (\weighty -> weightCheck (Cow nammy agey weighty))))
```

For `Maybe` the instance of `Monad` is [implemented as [src]](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#line-1005):

> ```
> instance  Monad Maybe  where
>     (Just x) >>= k      = k x
>     Nothing  >>= _      = Nothing
> ```

A `Maybe` can be seen as the result of a computation that can fail. The `Nothing` is the result of a computation that failed, and `Just …` as the result of the computation wrapped in a `Just` data constructor.

The instance of `Monad` enabes one to "chain" such computations. This means it will only return a `Just …` if all computations are successful (return a `Just …`). So in your expression:

```
mkSphericalCow' :: String -> Int -> Int -> Maybe Cow
mkSphericalCow' name' age' weight' = do
    nammy <- noEmpty name'
    agey <- noNegative age'
    weighty <- noNegative weight'
    weightCheck (Cow nammy agey weighty)
```

So if one or more of the functions `nonEmpty name'`, `nonNegative age'`, `nonNegative weight'` and `weightCheck (Cow nammy agey weighty)` returns `Nothing`, the entire `do` block will evaluate to `Nothing`. The left side of the `<-` arrow is the result of the computation where the `Just` is unwrapped. This unwrapping is done on the instance of the `Monad` where we see `(Just x) >>= k = …`, where the `Just` data constructor is thus unwrapped, and `x` is used as parameter to the `k` function.

You can here make it more convenient by writing it as:

```
mkSphericalCow' :: String -> Int -> Int -> Maybe Cow
mkSphericalCow' name' age' weight' = (Cow <$> noEmpty name' <*> nonNegative age' <*> noNegative weight') >>= weightCheck
```

Here we make use of the `Functor` and `Applicative` instance of `Maybe` where we thus will generate a `Maybe Cow`, that is a `Just (Cow a b c)` given `Just a = noEmpty name'`, `Just b = noNegative age'`, `Just c = noNegative weight'`. Then we thus make use of the `>>=` function to unwrap the `Just` data constructor and pass the value wrapped in the `Just` to the `weightCheck`.